# Make the page do nothing if $_GET is empty

Tags: php, mysql, get

I am trying to get my page to update a DB when there is `$_GET` data.

However even when www.myurl.com?status= is blank the page updates the DB with nothing.

Here is my code

```
$status=$_GET["status"];

$sql="UPDATE users SET status =$status WHERE personID='$user'" or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($sql);
```

Can anyone help? I am trying to get the page to do nothing if the URL is just www.myurl.com

Comment: `if (!empty($_GET)) {
    ... do stuff ...
} else {
    exit;
}`

Comment: soo.. why not just check the contents of that variable?

Comment: Sidenote: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and you will be hacked if you haven't been already. Please use prepared / parameterized queries to prevent this from happening. See also: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/)

Comment: You first of all need a function that returns you the request URI. So far this is missing.

Comment: lol set site-wide user status's in 1 injection query

Comment: This is prone to a SQL attack as said above.  Try switching to PDO or mysqli, prepares statements should help out.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!empty($_GET['status']) { // Check if `status` is not empty
    $sql="UPDATE users SET status = $_GET['status'] WHERE personID='$user'";
    mysql_query($sql);  // Continue with sql query
}
```

`empty` - https://www.php.net/empty

`isset` - https://www.php.net/isset

Comment: Whoever down voted this could you explain what's wrong with it?  I'm actually curious.

Comment: upvoted.... this is right.

Comment: it is not a question of being wrong - it is because you only provided the code without any explanation of what exactly needs to go into the `{ }`... beef up your answer and will be happy to upvote

Comment: @malta Hopefully that's a little better, sorry for not going the whole nine yards.

Comment: @malta I didn't care about the vote as much of what needed to be changed :)  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) in PHP to achieve this.

```
if(!empty($_GET["status"]))  //<--- Control to the inside will be passed only if the status variable is not empty
{
$status=$_GET["status"];
$sql="UPDATE users SET status =$status WHERE personID='$user'" or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($sql);
}
```

That was the first thing. Secondly you are using an obsolete deprecated API i.e. the `mysql_*` functions. You need to switch over to [`PreparedStatements`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: The `isset()` is unnecessary if using `!empty()`.

Comment: @AmalMurali, Isn't your comment synonymous to that of Nick's ? ;)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Nick doesn't explain *why*. (By the way, the downvote is *not* mine.)

Comment: @AmalMurali, Ah its ok thanks :) . I am used to downvotes :P